# Why non-adiabatic matrix is an antisymmetric matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In deriving coupling term beyond Born-Oppenheimer approximation, there is a term non-adiabatic coupling term written as:

$$
\tau_{ij} = \langle\zeta_i| \nabla\zeta_j\rangle
$$

where $\zeta$ here is the electronic eigenfunctions of electronic Hamiltonian.

Many online materials say that $\tau_{ij}$ is an antisymmetric matrix for a system of real electronic wave functions. Why? How can I proof that?

Comment: Quick hint: $\nabla\langle \zeta_i|\zeta_j\rangle=0$.

Comment: This answers my question! Much appreciated. @Sunyam